Catboost Feature Importance Calculation
I fitted a simple binary classification model with only 3 trees and wanted to check if feature importance results are simmillar to the formula in Catboost documentation (PredictionValuesChange).
After training the model, I followed steps in CatBoost JSON model tutorial and got the following tree structure:
{
  "leaf_values": [
    -0.13915912880676032,
    0.1097787155963716
  ],
  "leaf_weights": [
    2143.0251545906067,
    2252.974784851074
  ],
  "splits": [
    {
      "border": 3.5,
      "float_feature_index": 13,
      "split_index": 0,
      "split_type": "FloatFeature"
    }
  ]
} 

Each tree in the model is only depth = 1 and there is only one tree (index = 1) with the feature of interest. I decided to manually calculate the feature importance according to formula above and compare the results with .get_feature_importance method. The results were very different:

Feature Importance: 28.2947825
Manual Calculation: 68.06248029261762

Below is the code used for feature importance calculations:
tree_indx = 1
v_1 = model['oblivious_trees'][tree_indx]['leaf_values'][0]
v_2 = model['oblivious_trees'][tree_indx]['leaf_values'][1]

c_1 = model['oblivious_trees'][tree_indx]['leaf_weights'][0]
c_2 = model['oblivious_trees'][tree_indx]['leaf_weights'][1]

avr  = (v_1*c_1 + v_2*c_2)/(c_1+c_2)

fi  = ((v_1 - avr)**2)*c_1 + ((v_2 - avr)**2)*c_2
print(fi)

Am I making a mistake?

Just read that the feature importance values are normalised to sum up to 100:
https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/fstr#regular-feature-importance (Specifics section).

"Just read" - where? Please post a link to the relevant documentation

@desertnaut added the source.
